# PHP MAIL: Very Old Mail delivered now from 2014

Tags: php, email

I've a very big problem. I make a site 2 years ago with a contact form in php, and today I've received a lot of lost email, that where in a cue, I don't know where. I receveid more than 100 email from 2014 to today.
I'm using this php code:

```
<?php if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();

if ( !$_POST ) exit;

if ( !defined( "PHP_EOL" ) ) define( "PHP_EOL", "\r\n" );

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Simple Configuration Options

// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

$address = "mail@mail.itt";

// Twitter Direct Message notification control.
// Set $twitter_active to 0 to disable Twitter Notification
$twitter_active = 0;

// Get your consumer key and consumer secret from http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
// Notes:
// Application Name: Jigowatt Contact Form
// Description: Jigowatt Contact Form Direct Messaging Funcionality
// Application Website: (your website address)
// Application Type: Browser
// Callback URL: (Blank)
// Default Access type: Read and Write
$twitter_user    = ""; // Your user name
$consumer_key    = "";
$consumer_secret = "";

// Access Token and Access Token Secret is under "My Access Token" (right menu).
$token           = "";
$secret          = "";

// END OF Simple Configuration Options

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Do not edit the following lines
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$postValues = array();
foreach ( $_POST as $name => $value ) {
    $postValues[$name] = trim( $value );
}
extract( $postValues );


// Important Variables
// $posted_verify = isset( $postValues['verify'] ) ? md5( $postValues['verify'] ) : '';
// $session_verify = !empty($_SESSION['jigowatt']['ajax-extended-form']['verify']) ? $_SESSION['jigowatt']['ajax-extended-form']['verify'] : '';

$error = '';

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Begin verification process
//
// You may add or edit lines in here.
//
// To make a field not required, simply delete the entire if statement for that field.
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////
// Name field is required
if ( empty( $name ) ) {
    $error .= '<li>Il suo nome è necessario.</li>';
}
////////////////////////




////////////////////////
// Email field is required
if ( empty( $email ) ) {
    $error .= '<li>La sua mail è necessaria</li>';
} elseif ( !isEmail( $email ) ) {
    $error .= '<li>Ha inserito un indirizzo e-mail errato</li>';
}
////////////////////////

////////////////////////
// Phone field is required
if ( empty( $phone ) ) {
    $error .= '<li>Il suo numero di telefono è necessario</li>';
}
////////////////////////

////////////////////////
// City field is required
if ( empty( $city ) ) {
    $error .= "<li>La sua città ci è necessaria per individuare l'agente o il punto vendita a lei più vicino</li>";
}
////////////////////////

////////////////////////
// Phone field is required
// if ( empty( $phone ) ) {
//  $error .= '<li>Your phone number is required.</li>';
// } elseif ( !is_numeric( $phone ) ) {
//  $error .= '<li>Your phone number can only contain digits.</li>';
// }
////////////////////////


////////////////////////
// Comments field is required
if ( empty( $message ) ) {
    $error .= '<li>Dovreste inserire il messaggio.</li>';
}
////////////////////////


////////////////////////
// Agree to terms checkbox is required
// if ( empty( $agree ) ) {
//  $error .= '<li>You must agree to our terms.</li>';
// }
////////////////////////


////////////////////////
// Verification code is required
// if ( $session_verify != $posted_verify ) {
//  $error .= '<li>The verification code you entered is incorrect.</li>';
// }
////////////////////////

if ( !empty($error) ) {
    echo '<div class="alert red"><h3>Attenzione! Per favore corregga gli errori e provi ancora.</h3>';
    echo '<ul class="error_messages">' . $error . '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';

    // Important to have return false in here.
    return false;

}

// Advanced Configuration Option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

$e_subject = "Contatto dal sito da : " . $name;

// Advanced Configuration Option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$msg  = "Nome: $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg  .= "Email: $email" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg  .= "Città: $city" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "Telefono: $phone" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= $message . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
// $msg .= "$name chose option: $optionsRadios";
$msg .= "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "Questo messaggio vi è stato inviato tramite il modulo di contatto del sito www.sito.it";

// if ( $twitter_active == 1 ) {

//  $twitter_msg = $name . " - " . $comments . ". You can contact " . $name . " via email, " . $email ." or via phone " . $phone . ".";
//  twittermessage( $twitter_user, $twitter_msg, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $secret );

// }

$msg = wordwrap( $msg, 70 );

$headers  = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if ( mail( $address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers ) ) {

    // echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div class='alert green'>";
    echo "<h3>Email inviata correttamente.</h3>";
    echo "<p>Grazie <strong>$name</strong>, il suo messaggio ci è stato inviato</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    // echo "</fieldset>";

    // Important to have return false in here.
    return false;

}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Do not edit below this line
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo 'ERROR! Please confirm PHP mail() is enabled.';
return false;

// function twittermessage( $user, $message, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $secret ) { // Twitter Direct Message function, do not edit.

//  require_once 'twitter/EpiCurl.php';
//  require_once 'twitter/EpiOAuth.php';
//  require_once 'twitter/EpiTwitter.php';

//  $Twitter = new EpiTwitter( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret );
//  $Twitter->setToken( $token, $secret );

//  $direct_message = $Twitter->post_direct_messagesNew( array( 'user' => $user, 'text' => $message ) );
//  $tweet_info = $direct_message->responseText;

// }

function isEmail( $email ) { // Email address verification, do not edit.

    return preg_match( "/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email );

}
?>
```

But I don't understand where to search... I don't find an smtp that this script use to send email, so how can they be sended and remain in this cue for all this time?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter this command in Linux command prompt

> find /var/spool/mqueue -type f | wc -l and this find /var/spool/mqueue-rx -type f | wc -l

Comment: on linux? I don't have nothing, only an ftp to work on that site.. My hoster give me only that. Nothing to operate on consolle or other

Comment: You could try a reverse shell!?